# Import model from 3dStudioMax into THREE.js

Tags: 3d, three.js, 3dsmax

I know that THREE.js has importers from various 3d graphics formats.

Is there an importer suitable to display a model created in 3dStudioMax? And if there is not one, is there a way to convert a 3dStudioMax model in something that can be imported in THREE.js?

Comment: By the way, this would be an excellent question for the proposed 3d stackexchange at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5022/3d-graphics-modeling-applications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is a MAXScript script that will convert a selected object's mesh into JSON. At the time of this post, it was available in the SVN of the [3ds Max developer community](http://3ds-max-dev.googlecode.com) at Google code hosting.

```
tmesh = snapshotAsMesh selection[1]
out_file = createfile "$scripts\\output.json

num_faces = tmesh.numfaces
num_verts = tmesh.numverts 

fn PrintPoint pt = (
 format "%, %, %, " pt.x pt.y pt.z to:out_file
)   

fn PrintPointUV pt = (
 format "%, %, " pt.x pt.y to:out_file
)   

fn PrintPointInt pt = (
    x = int(pt.x) - 1
    y = int(pt.y) - 1
    z = int(pt.z) - 1
    format "%, %, %, " x y z to:out_file
)   

format "{\n" to:out_file

-- Vertex Positions 
-- format "    \"vertexPositions\" : [" to:out_file
format "    positions : [" to:out_file
for i = 1 to num_verts do
(
 vert = getVert tmesh i
 PrintPoint vert
)
format "],\n" to:out_file

-- Vertex Normals
-- format "    \"vertexNormals\" : [" to:out_file
format "    normals : [" to:out_file
for i = 1 to num_verts do
(
  vert = getNormal tmesh i
  PrintPoint vert
)
format "],\n" to:out_file

-- Vertex Texture Coordinates 
-- format "    \"vertexTextureCoords\" : [" to:out_file
format "    uv : [" to:out_file
for i = 1 to num_faces do
(
    -- Iterate over faces 
    tvface = getTVFace tmesh i
    for j = 1 to 3 do (
        -- Get a specific texture vertex
        tvert = getTVert tmesh tvface[j]        
        PrintPointUV tvert
    )
)
format "],\n" to:out_file

-- Face Indexes
-- format "    \"indices\" : [" to:out_file
format "    indices : [" to:out_file
for f = 1 to num_faces do
(
   face = getFace tmesh f
   PrintPointInt face
)
format "],\n" to:out_file

format "}" to:out_file

close out_file
delete tmesh
edit out_name
```

Answer (score 18):

You have two options:

1) Use ThreeJSExporter.ms but take into account that is no longer mantained:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/max

2) **(Recommended)** Use OBJ exporter option in 3DS Max. Then use convert_obj_three.py script available here:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/utils/converters/obj/convert_obj_three.py

More detailed info in my issue on Three.js's Github:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/893

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used three.js in a while, but I know it imports OBJ which 3dsmax can easily export and there is a python script that converts an .obj to a three.js .json mesh.

I noticed that in the latest revision there is a [MaxScript Exporter](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/utils/exporters/max/ThreeJSExporter.ms) straight to the json format, so start with that. It should generate a .js file based on the selected mesh, but can't access a PC at the moment to test.

Answer (score 1):

You can save max file using 3ds file format. Open 3ds model 
with the [**A3dsViewer**](http://www.aptagraphis.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=59%3aa3dsviewer-16-released&catid=1%3alatest-news&Itemid=1). Click Export to the HTML5 in the toolbar and 
you will be able to preview the model in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Now in 2018, we do have [glTF](https://www.khronos.org/gltf/) and a very nice exporter for 3ds max, developed and actively maintained by the babylon community:

[image]

Description and how to install is extensively described here:

https://doc.babylonjs.com/resources/3dsmax_to_gltf

The gltf models can then easily be used in three.js, see some examples:

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_gltf.html

https://threejs.org/examples/#misc_exporter_gltf

Enjoy!